# In-Context Checkout inconsistent

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement the In-Context Express Checkout.  The behavior is very inconsistent.  Sometimes, I will get the overlay window, other times the overlay closes and I get redirected to the old express checkout.  In both instances, I am getting back a valid token.

Working Properly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHIwB.png

Redirected:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHaOK.png

Comment: Another note.Even the demos from PayPals integration guide exhibit the same behavior for me.


[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfNSVRyq86pDR5mH4HH?p=preview)


[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/x1cmeq1cFXQNNAtAe4GP?p=preview)

Comment: Did you resolve the issue???

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

in-context flow has some restricted parameters, when passed can hinder the pop-up and redirect to classic checkout.

1. Click [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/) to view restricted parameters-
   *Feature or integration supported by in-context checkout* section
2. If you're not passing any restricted parameters, then send your nvp array request for the setExpressCheckout
3. Let me know and I'll help you out